# Multiple TextClips in one Video moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

How can I add the watermarks into the video.

```
positions = [("right", "top"), ("left", "top"), ("right", "bottom"), ("left", "bottom")]
watermarks = []
video = VideoFileClip(
    clip)
duration = video.duration/4
for i in range(1,5):
    watermark = make_text("u/reddit", 10, "white", duration*i, duration*i, video.duration, positions[i-1]) #make_etext returns TextClip
    watermarks.append(watermark)

result.write_videofile("watermarked.mp4", fps=30, codec="mpeg4")
```

Comment: `set_position` and `CompositeVideoClip`

Comment: `set_position` is only available for VideoClips or how should I use it?

When I use this `result = CompositeVideoClip([video, watermarks])` I get an error because I can not give a watermarks as a list do I need to change it in any way?

Comment: A `TextClip` is a subclass of a `VideoClip` so it has `set_position`. Use `[video] + watermarks` to get a flat list.